# 'Placeholder' character to avoid positive comparison?

Tags: java, arrays, string, compare

I am working through the [CodingBat exercises for Java](http://codingbat.com/prob/p139677). I came across the following question:

> Given 2 arrays that are the same length containing strings, compare the 1st string in one array to the 1st string in the other array, the 2nd to the 2nd and so on. Count the number of times that the 2 strings are non-empty and start with the same char. The strings may be any length, including 0.

My code is this:

```
public int matchUp(String[] a, String[] b){

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        String firstLetterA = a[i].length() == 0
                            ? "ê"
                            : a[i].substring(0, 1);
        String firstLetterB = b[i].length() == 0
                            ? "é"
                            : b[i].substring(0, 1);

        if (firstLetterA.equals(firstLetterB)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

My question is: Which 'placeholder' character would be considered good practice to use to avoid unwanted comparison between `firstLetterA` and `firstLetterB`?

In this case, I have simply assigned two differing letters that are seldom used (at least, in English). I tried just using `''` (an empty character, not a space) but of course, they match each other. I also tried using `null` for both, because I assumed it could not be positively compared, but that causes problems too.

Comment: why do you want/need a placeholder? why not just compare first chars when there is one, and take another action when the string length is zero?

Comment: You could use `charAt()` instead of `substring()`, so it doesn't create a new `String` every time.

Comment: Important note: This and the accepted answer will not necessarily work properly if using things like accented characters, etc. due to the fact that the composition might be different between strings. This may or may not be desirable behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A good practice — IMO — is to extend `if` condition and not to use any dummy characters at all:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (!a[i].isEmpty() && !b[i].isEmpty() && a[i].charAt(0) == b[i].charAt(0)) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the alternative solution.

- iterate nested 2d loops for each array
- check if characters are same in both array with respective order and
  length of string
- compare character by subString method.
- increase count

.

```
public static int matchingChar(String[] a, String[] b) {
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++) {
            if(i==j && a[i].length()!=0 && b[i].length()!=0) {
                if(a[i].startsWith(b[i].substring(0,1))) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
public int matchUp(String[] a, String[] b) {
  int count = 0;
  
  for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
  {
    if(a[i].equals("") || b[i].equals(""))
      continue;
    if(a[i].charAt(0) == b[i].charAt(0))
      count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Continue to the next element when the current element of array is empty.